# Checking if form submitted when one form calls another

Tags: php, forms

I have one page with a form that submits to a second page with its own form.

In the second page,

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
```

always returns true and the if condition executes - I'm not sure if its because its called from a first form itself - but normally that's what I do to check the form is submitted, and it works as expected. Ie, as soon as the page/form opens, it executes the code inside the condition, when obviously it should not.

I need to be able to check in the second form when it is submitted itself ?

Its just a standard short form with its own button

```
<input type='submit' value='GO!'>
```

It comes from a first form with its own button

```
<input type='submit' value='Delete'>
```

Comment: Does the second form action on itself ? Or does it action on another file. Even if the action is set to itself you can add a hidden field for second form and check whether that is set and you will know whether it was submitted

Comment: Post the entire code.

Comment: yes it actions itself - true I can add another hidden field, but i'm not sure why it's necessary

Comment: Because you have to differentiate between the two forms if everything actions on one place. Or you could name the submit button somerhing else

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Php code :

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just noting that I solved this by checking for the `name` of the submit button, by adding the name:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Go!">
```

Then checking both

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (isset($_POST['delete']))){
```